# click thumbnail image then a youtube video

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

- Please help me make this video, you view link http://sawareru.jp/
- I want to make the same as video box of this. Can you give me some codes's js for that?
- **explain:** the first video box has a thumbnail picture, when click on this thumbnail is show video' youtube and when the stopping video show again thumbnail.

Comment: It's just a div over the iframe.

Comment: _Can you give me some codes's js for that?_ What have you tried,where did you get stuck? SO is for helping out developers with problems they are facing with their code, not an NGO for free code.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to play the video on your own html page, you can do this.

```
<iframe width="420" height="345"
src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/SPbBdqqcsFY">
</iframe>
```

or

```
<embed
width="420" height="345"
src="http://www.youtube.com/v/SPbBdqqcsFY"
type="application/x-shockwave-flash">
</embed>
```

Overlay i would suggest that you made a Jquery like:

```
<div id="overlay">Click to watch video</div>


$("#overlay").click(function () {
    $(this).html(your stuff goes here)
});
```